# Change the color of a single menu item in Bootstrap Nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the color of my "Logout" menu item in Bootstrap 3. I have tried giving it a "logout-menu" class but it is not working.

This works and changes the font color for all menu items:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: #930008;
}
```

This works and changes the color for hover states

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li > a:hover{
    color: #4e5255;
}
```

This does **NOT** work. This "logout-menu" item is not blue. It is the same color as the above styles (#930008)

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.logout-menu  li a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Here is the HTML showing the class "logout-menu" on the logout a tag.

```
<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-container">
      <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
        <li class="logout-menu"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

How can I change the color of just the logout item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong Syntax

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li.logout-menu a {
  color: blue;
 }
```

try this.

I think you need to use !important also.

Comment: Works!! Didn't need the !important though. Works without it.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id say logout.

and style it

```
#logout:hover{
color: #4e5255; 

  }
```